# Access a super class variable while working with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, class

I've a class with a list of threads, and those need to access a variable in the superclass. I'm not sure how to access that variable in a safe way for threads to do their thing.

An idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
from threading import Thread


class Parent():

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.arr = []

    def run(self):
        self.arr.append(Child(25))
        self.arr.append(Child(50))
        for child in a.arr:
            child.start()
        for child in a.arr:
            child.join()
        print(self.num)


class Child(Thread, Parent):

    def __init__(self, sum):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sum = sum

    def run(self):
        # every thread should a.num + self.sum so I end up with a.num = 175
        pass


a = Parent(100)
a.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular example, you want:

1. Pass parent to children, so they know who they should refer to
2. Use `Lock` to synchronize critical section (addition)

Like this:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

class Parent:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
        self.arr = []
        self.lock = Lock()  # Create the Lock

    def run(self):
        self.arr.append(Child(25, self))  # pass parent to children
        self.arr.append(Child(50, self))  # 
        for child in a.arr:
            child.start()
        for child in a.arr:
            child.join()
        print(self.num)

class Child(Thread, Parent):

    def __init__(self, sum_, parent):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sum_ = sum_
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        with self.parent.lock:  # this with section will be synchronized
                                # against parent's lock
            self.parent.num += self.sum_

a = Parent(100)
a.run()
```